# Datatable not displaying all table columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, twig, html-table

I have a very weird bahaviour with the library DataTable.

I have a classical table build with a loop of 14 elements. When displayed normaly, everything appears, when I make it a DataTable, the last 4 columns disappear.

My code where horizon has the value 14 (tested) and which only shows 10 columns of the loop (displays everything if I remove the DataTable class) :

```
<table id="ingredients_table" class="table DataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Produit</th>
            <th>Marque</th>
            <th title="Quantité disponible dans un produit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">Packaging</th>
            <th title="Unité de gestion des stocks" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">UGS</th>
            <th>Stock min</th>
            <th>Stock actuel</th>
            <th class="text-right">J+</th>
            {% for i in 1..horizon %}
                <th>{{ i }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% spaceless %}
        {% for ingredient in ingredients -%}
            <tr data-table_form_id="{{ ingredient.id }}" data-id="{{ ingredient.id }}" data-repo="AppBundle:FoodAnalytics\UserIngredient">
                <td>{{ ingredient.getInferredName }}</td>
                <td>{{ ingredient.getProductBrand }}</td>
                <td>{{ ingredient.getProductPackaging }}</td>
                <td style="min-width: 100px !important;" data-table_form_value="{{ ingredient.unit.id }}">
                    {{ ingredient.unit }}
                </td>
                <td style="min-width: 70px !important;">
                    {{ ingredient.stockMini | round_quantity }}
                </td>
                <td style="min-width: 70px !important;">
                    {{ ingredient.getLastNumberObjectValue() }}
                </td>
                <td><span class="sparkline" data-id="{{ ingredient.id }}"></span></td>
                {% for i in 1..horizon %}
                    {% if stocks[ingredient.id][i] < 0 %}
                        {% set class = 'text-danger' %}
                    {% elseif stocks[ingredient.id][i] < ingredient.stockMini %}
                        {% set class = 'text-warning' %}
                    {% endif %}
                    <td{% if class is defined %} class="{{ class }}"{% endif %}>
                        {{ stocks[ingredient.id][i]|round_quantity }}
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endspaceless %}
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Produit</th>
        <th>Marque</th>
        <th title="Quantité disponible dans un produit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">Packaging</th>
        <th title="Unité de gestion des stocks" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">UGS</th>
        <th>Stock min</th>
        <th>Stock actuel</th>
        <th class="text-right">J+</th>
        {% for i in 1..horizon %}
            <th>{{ i }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

$('.DataTable').DataTable({iDisplayLength: 50, responsive: true});
```

Does someone has an idea of what's wrong ?

[image: Table only displaying 10 of the loop 14 columns]

Comment: ok, found it, it comes from the responsive option of the dataTable initialization. Why is this doing this? It's not expected.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.DataTable').DataTable({iDisplayLength: 50, responsive: true});
});
```

Comment: my js line was a code snippet, was already in a document ready function. I had to remove the responsive option to make it work